# Multiple errors during the gradle sync when I try to add Google Service library to the dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I want to add to my app some ads using AdMob, the site says I need to add Google Services to the dependencies to use this functionality. So with Android Studio I went to File->Project Structure->app->Dependencies, I clicked on the "+" button e searched for "play-services". What I found was "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0" so I added it to the dependencies. During the gradle sync however Android Studio sends some errors and stops the gradle sync.

This is the log I get form the sync: http://pastebin.com/ZpN4RUcm

Here some data that might be useful:

- Compile SDK Version: API 17
- Build Tools Version: 23.0.1
- Android
  Studio 2.1.2

This is my main gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And this is my app gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:17'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.serpenssolida.glowdodger"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
       }
   }

   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:17.0.0'
       compile files('libs/processing-core.jar')
       compile project(':facebook')
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
   }
```

How can I get rid of all the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Change your app gradle file as below and try again:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion '24'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried and didn't work. The output remain the same. EDIT: Actually gradle gave me a warning. Fixed, I'm trying again.

Comment: After some trouble I managed to make my app run without errors! Editing the gradle as your answer say has worked! +1